# How to subset a vector by intervals of 10?

Tags: r, vector, subset

Here is a list of numbers from 94 - 195:

```
l = c(94:195)
```

How can I generate a new vector based on intervals of ten within the range of `l`?  This is what I am after:

```
100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this simple approach

```
> l[l %% 10 == 0]
 [1] 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `seq`:

```
seq(10*ceiling(min(l)/10), 10*floor(max(l)/10) , by=10)
```

It works well when `l` is not the well ordered sequence of integers of the example:

```
l <- runif(10, 94, 195)
l
seq(10*ceiling(min(l)/10), 10*floor(max(l)/10) , by=10)
```